# #What causes different behaviour between stats and ggplot2 when writing histograms, normal curves and qqplots to .pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I need to produce plots for statistical analyses and I am stumped by a difference in behaviour between stats and ggplot. Who can help out?
I am trying to produce a pdf with histograms, including normal curves, side-by-side with qqplots, with the next plot continuing on the same page. Preferably using ggplot (because prettier plots). I have a large number of variables in my real dataset, so I am using a 'for' loop.

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(stats)  
library(datasets)
```

This piece of ggplot code does what I want it to do.

```
ggplot(airquality, aes(Wind)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),colour = "black", fill = "white") + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(airquality$Wind), sd = sd(airquality$Wind)), colour = "red", size = 1) + 
  xlab("Wind")
qplot(sample = airquality$Wind, stat = "qq")
```

I am fine with the binwidth warning, I want that picked automatically, and I will build in a suppression for that message later on. I am not sure wat to do though with: '"stat" is deprecated' Anyone?
If I try to work this into a 'for' loop, I cannot get it to work. It keeps putting every plot on a new page and it leaves out the normal curves:

```
Variablesairquality<-c("Wind", "Temp", "Month", "Day") 
pdf(file = "Normality.pdf", 4, 5)
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for(i in Variablesairquality){
  plot(ggplot(airquality, aes(airquality[,i])) + 
         geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),colour = "black", fill = "white") + 
         stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(airquality[,i]), sd = sd(airquality[,i])), colour = "red", size = 1) + 
         xlab(i)
      )
  plot(qplot(sample = airquality[,i], stat = "qq" )
  )
}
dev.off()
```

Which I don’t get, because if I try it using stats, it does exactly what I want:

```
pdf(file = "Normality2.pdf", 4, 5)
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for(i in Variablesairquality){
  h <- hist(airquality[,i], col = "white", cex.axis=0.50, xlab = i, cex.lab=0.75, main = paste("Distribution"), cex.main= 0.75) 
  xfit<-seq(min(airquality[,i]),max(airquality[,i]),length=length(airquality[,i])) 
  yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(airquality[,i]),sd=sd(airquality[,i])) 
  yfit <- yfit*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(airquality[,i]) 
  lines(xfit, yfit, col="red", lwd=1)
  qqnorm(airquality[,i], cex = 0.5, cex.axis=0.50, cex.lab=0.75, main = expression("Q-Q plot for"~paste(i)), cex.main= 0.75)
  qqline(airquality[,i], col = "red")
}
dev.off()
```

(Accept for the thing with the main label which I still need to figure out. Anyone any tips?)
I would be most grateful if someone could point out the mistake in my ggplot code or otherwise explain this behaviour. Thanks!
I use R-programming V3.2.3 and R-studio v0.99.891. (And yes, I read every similar item here, scowered the internet and I read the help files; that did not get me where I need to go.)

Comment: (1) **ggplot2** uses grid graphics, whereas `hist` et al use base graphics. The two systems are entirely different. Hence, `par()` has _zero_ effect on **ggplot2**; it is base graphics only. Look at `grid.arrange` from the **gridExtra** package. (2) grid graphics are `print`ed not `plot`ed.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate. You should use `ggplot(airquality, aes_string(i))`. However, `par` is for base graphics and not for grid graphics. Look into package `gridExtra` and in particular its `grid.arrange` function.

Comment: Thanks Joran and Roland! I am looking into gridExtra now. Would you by any chance know of an example where grid.arrange is worked into a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

On `` `stat` is deprecated ``, see [Deprecated features](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/releases/tag/v2.0.0) in the **ggplot2 2.0.0** release notes.  Use instead:

```
ggplot(airquality, aes(sample = Wind)) +
  stat_qq()
```

---

If you don't wish to use `gridExtra::grid.arrange`, here's an approach that uses facets.  Begin by wrangling the data into a new dataframe with the values we want for x, y, plot type, and geom variables:

```
d <- as.data.frame(qqnorm(airquality$Wind, plot.it = F))
d$plot <- "QQ plot"
d$geom <- "point"
d <- rbind(d, data.frame(x = airquality$Wind, y = NA, 
                         plot = "Histogram", geom = "bar"))
d <- rbind(d, with(airquality, data.frame(
                x = seq(min(Wind), max(Wind), l = 100), 
                y = dnorm(seq(min(Wind), max(Wind), l = 100), 
                          mean = mean(Wind), sd = sd(Wind)),
                plot = "Histogram", geom = "line")))
```

Then call `ggplot`, subsetting the data as appropriate for each geom:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + facet_wrap(~plot, scales = "free") +
  geom_histogram(data = subset(d, plot == "Histogram" & geom == "bar"),
                 aes(y = ..density..), 
                 colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  geom_line(data = subset(d, plot == "Histogram" & geom == "line"),
            colour = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = subset(d, plot == "QQ plot")) +
  labs(x = "Wind")
```

Output:

[image]

---

To do multiple plots, you can wrap the code above into a for loop, making sure to wrap `ggplot` inside `print`:

```
pdf("path/to/pdf/out.pdf")
Variablesairquality <- c("Wind", "Temp", "Month", "Day") 
for (i in rev(Variablesairquality)) { 
  x <- airquality[[i]]
  d <- as.data.frame(qqnorm(x, plot.it = F)) 
  d$plot <- "QQ plot" 
  d$geom <- "point" 
  d <- rbind(d, data.frame(x = x, y = NA, plot = "Histogram", geom = "bar")) 
  d <- rbind(d, data.frame(x = seq(min(x), max(x), l = 100), 
                           y = dnorm(seq(min(x), max(x), l = 100), 
                                     mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)),
                           plot = "Histogram", geom = "line"))

  print(
    ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + facet_wrap(~plot, scales = "free") +
      geom_histogram(data = subset(d, plot == "Histogram" & geom == "bar"),
                     aes(y = ..density..), 
                     colour = "black", fill = "white") +
      geom_line(data = subset(d, plot == "Histogram" & geom == "line"),
                colour = "red", size = 1) +
      geom_point(data = subset(d, plot == "QQ plot")) +
      labs(x = i)
  )
} 
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks! I will go and look into that.

Comment: That is a very nice solution, thank you Weihuang Wong. I have now tried to turn that into a for loop, but the result is a dataframe where all the qqplots are done first, than the histograms, and than all normal curves. I was thinking I could add a sorting variable and than restructure the dataframe with dplyr (not succesfull so far), but perhaps you know a better way of going about this. Here is my attempt so far:

Comment: `Variablesairquality<-c("Wind", "Temp", "Month", "Day")   
for(i in Variablesairquality){  
d <- as.data.frame(qqnorm(airquality[,i], plot.it = F))  
d$plot <- "QQ plot"  
d$geom <- "point"  
d <- rbind(d, data.frame(x = airquality[,i], y = NA,   
                         plot = "Histogram", geom = "bar"))  
d <- rbind(d, with(airquality, data.frame(x = airquality[,i],   
                                          y = dnorm(airquality[,i], mean = mean etc.  
d$indepentvar <- airquality[,i]
}`

Comment: Or perhaps something like this would be better (also unsuccessful): `plotsdata <- lapply(Variablesairquality,plotsfunction) 
plotsfunction <- function(airquality){
  (d <- as.data.frame(qqnorm(airquality$Wind, plot.it = F))
  d$plot <- "QQ plot"
  d$geom <- "point"
  d <- rbind(d, data.frame(x = airquality$Wind, y = NA, 
                         plot = "Histogram", geom = "bar"))
  d <- rbind(d, with(airquality,   etc.  d)
} `